# How to handle creation of referenced documents in Mongoose and Node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Node.js API method that creates a Track document and then creates Task document (which has DBRef to a Track to work on) to actually convert and upload it to s3 (specific operations doesn't really matter). I use Mongoose to perform operations on my MongoDB.

So my question is there any way to avoid having "stalled" tracks that have Track document created and no Task for them? Creating a Task without Track is fine though, but in that case we don't have DBRef until we create a Track document and then update a Task document which may fail due to server restart or something.

In traditional RDBMS that kind of problem is easy to solve since I would do that in a single transaction.

Thanks in advance.

Update:
My schemas look like that:

```
var Track = new Schema({
    name: String,
    ...
});


var Task = new Schema({
    track: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Track'},
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

Comment: what is your problem? to create a track without task?? or to not allow that? Also, Please post some code, if you have tried any.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your schemas. But, couldn't you just ref it the other way around? "Creating a Task without Track is fine though"  Could you create the Task, then later, when you create the Track, pass the _id from the Task from the client?

Comment: @ravishankar To not allow that. I will post my code later but I don't see how that would help

Comment: @NoobSter Creating reference another way around is the nice thought. It's kinda weird, but it will work.

Comment: The true NOSQL way would be to nest / make sub documents of Tracks within Task. However, the document cap is 16MB. if each Tracks have Task that grow without limit, though, you'll want to ref / emulate the join as you have planned.

Comment: Well I want to be able to query all the Tracks of a certain user for example and I want the Track to be visible to the user right after I create a Track-Task pair. And I also delete Task after I completed it.